# Sort Array in Ascending order by it's value. Lower value come first and then Higher values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looking for a solution to sort an array based on value. The minimum value will come first and then a higher value respectively.

The values are as below (" inch sing is required for some values):

```
array( '1/3', '1/4', '1', '4"', '18 11/12"', '18 1/4"', '2-3/8', '3-3/9' )
```

The code I have created for this is

```
$array=array( '1/3', '1/4', '1','4"', '18 11/12"', '18 1/4"', '2-3/8', '3-3/9');

foreach( $array as $k=>$v )
{
    $copy[$k] = preg_match("/(\d+)\/(\d+)/",$v,$m)?$m[1]/$m[2]+(int)$v:(int)$v;
}

array_multisort( $copy, SORT_NUMERIC, $array );

print_r( $array );
```

Expected result

```
array( '1/4', '1/3', '1', '2-3/8', '3-3/9', '4"', '18 1/4"', '18 11/12"' );
```

Comment: First, you need a parser that computes expressions like 18 1/4 ". It is not clear from your example what this parser has to do.

Comment: So, `18 11/12` is a mixed fraction?

Answer (score 0):

The code I have updated is below and it gives me the output exactly what I want. Hope this will help you if you want this kind of sorting.

```
function fractionToDecimal( $fraction ) 
{
    preg_match('/^(?P<whole>\d+)?\s?((?P<numerator>\d+)\/(?P<denominator>\d+))?$/', $fraction, $components);

    $whole = $components['whole'] ?: 0;
    $numerator = $components['numerator'] ?: 0;
    $denominator = $components['denominator'] ?: 0;

    $decimal = $whole;
    $numerator && $denominator && $decimal += ($numerator/$denominator);

    return $decimal;
}

$copy  = array();
$array = array('1/3','1/4','1','4"','18 11/12"','18 1/4"','2-3/8','3-3/9');

foreach( $array as $k => $v )
{
    $midval = round(fractionToDecimal($v),2);

    if( $midval == 0 )
    {
        $copy[$k] = preg_match("/(\d+)\/(\d+)/",$v,$m)?$m[1]/$m[2]+(int)$v:(int)$v;
    }
    else
    {
        $copy[$k] = $midval;
    }
}
array_multisort( $copy, $array );
print_r( $array );
```